# Inverse of a symmetric, diagonal dominant, M-matrix is diagonal dominant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $A$ is symmetric positive definite, diagonal dominant $(|a_{ii}|\ge \sum_{i\ne j} |a_{ij}|)$ and is M-matrix:
$A$ is symmetric $\Rightarrow$ $A^{-1}$ is symmetric
$A$ is an M-matrix $\Rightarrow$ $A^{-1}$ is positive

Further assumption: $a_{ij} \le 0, i\ne j, a_{ii} \ge 0$

Is $A^{-1}$ diagonal dominant?
Is there any reference which claims that $A^{-1}$ is diagonal dominant?

I test it with some matrices and look like $A^{-1}$ is diagonal dominant. However, I cannot find any document which states that.
Any help from you is highly appreciated!